# JavaScript scroll to location ABOVE specified DIV, i.e. 45 pixels above

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-animate, smooth-scrolling

I am creating a webpage and am interested in having my page scroll to a specific location + a certain number of pixels. I have found a number of smooth-scrolling examples online, but I can't seem to figure out how to set it to be, lets say, exactly 45 pixels above the target.

The code in my JavasSript file that I am currently using looks like the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    //smoothscroll
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).off("scroll");

        $('a').each(function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        })
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var target = this.hash,
            menu = target;
        $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate(
        {'scrollTop': $target.offset().top}
        , 1200, 'swing', function () 
        {window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);}
        );
    });
});

function onScroll(event){
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    $('.navigation a').each(function () {
        var currLink = $(this);
        var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
        if (refElement.position().top-170<= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
            $('.navigation ul li a').removeClass("active");
            currLink.addClass("active");
        }
    });
}
```

I have been able to get myself half way there by adding `.offset().top-45` to the line `{'scrollTop': $target.offset().top-45}`, and it works PERFECTLY on Chrome; but with every other major browser, it scrolls to the perfect location (45 pixels above the target), then "snaps" back to the initial location (which is lower than I would like).

I have also tried adding `.offset().top-45` to the line `{'scrollTop': {window.location.hash = target.offset().top-45}`, which works PERFECTLY on Chrome. It actually works in IE as well, although only for the first selection - after which it becomes unresponsive.

My reason for trying to do this is because I have a floating nav bar on the top of the page that is 45 pixels tall, and so I want the page to scroll to the proper location + 45 pixels in order to avoid having the nav bar hide anything.

Comment: Put a hidden HTML div that is 45 pixels above the element you want it above. Then scroll to that div.

Comment: Good idea.  I gave that a try, and it does the job! Only thing is now I have an additional 45px high white space above each section.  Because my site is basic, I can color them the same as the background, but then I would have to go into each section and make them each 45px shorter.  Before I go ahead and do that work, are there any other suggestions?

-I tried using display: none; but then the id cannot be linked on the page.
-also tried visibility: hidden; does nothing.

Comment: I believe that's caused by the `window.location.hash = target;` in the complete-function of the animation in //smoothscroll. When the animation is finished that sets the scrollTop to the location of the hash, which is the `target` and not `target-45`. Not sure why chrome doesn't do that though. (btw, the hidden-div-solution sounds like a terrible idea and should be an absolute last resort..)

Comment: Just to be clear, chrome is working exactly how I want it to.  I.E/Firefox are giving me issues (haven't tried Opera yet).

I'll do just that, leave the hidden divs to a last resort; hoping I can find a solution rather than a work-around if possible.

Comment: That's what I'm saying: because of the issue stated in my previous comment, IE and FF snap back after the scroll. I was only wondering why chrome doesn't do that too, because strictly speaking it should snap back as well, just like the other browsers. (But then again, chrome is often more forgiving than other browsers in these kind of situations)

Comment: And just to make myself absolutely clear, what I'm getting at is this: The fact that Chrome does exactly what you want, doesn't mean that it does what it should do, strictly obeying the code. Consequently, it doesn't mean your code is correct or that the other browsers are doing something wrong. The forgiving nature of Chrome can be handy if you only need to rely on Chrome, but if you want cross-browser functionality, it can make it even harder in situations like this to find that bug in your code..